# Only featured questions being shown

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Why are only featured questions being shown at this URL?

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook

Before, this URL would show all questions tagged with 'facebook'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that you have click "featured" from the homepage then navigated to tagged/facebook.

It will keep your initial selection when browsing elsewhere e.g. through each of the tags.

Comment: How do you get rid of it again having clicked it?

Comment: Go to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions and click "Newest" should sort it out?

Comment: That worked. Thank you! It's a shame that when you are looking at a tagged set of questions that there isn't the same marker to say you have filtered by featured or newest or active etc, that there is if you look at all questions (which I never do - until just now).